# Getting output data from console application

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am new to .NET programming. I referred to a tutorial while creating this project. I have a dll file that does add and subtract functions:

**ClassLibraryDll.dll**

```
public class MathClass
{
    //method for Addition
    public static long Add(long num1, long num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    //method for Subtraction
    public static long Sub(long num1, long num2)
    {
        return num1 - num2;
    }
}
```

I have an .NET Console Application which has a program class which will make reference to the dll file and will use the functions from the dll file and take in two integers as input and display an output according to the function chosen.

**Program.cs**

```
using ClassLibraryDll;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MathClass.Add(10, 10);
        Console.WriteLine("Calling methods from ClassLibraryDLL:");

        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: TestCode <num1> <num2>");
            return;
        }

        long num1 = long.Parse(args[0]);
        long num2 = long.Parse(args[1]);

        long sum = MathClass.Add(num1, num2);
        long substract = MathClass.Sub(num1, num2);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, sum);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", num1, num2, substract);

     }
}
```

The output I am suppose to get assuming 1 and 1 are entered as command line args:

`Calling methods from ClassLibraryDll:`

`1 + 1 = 2`

`1 - 1 = 0`

I am unsure how to get the output from the console application. When I run the console application, I am unable to input any integers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfWgM.jpg)

Someone please help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.net. Did you mean just `.net` (dotnet)?

Comment: Hi i have edited that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `Console.ReadLine` method, which waits for the user to input a line of text.

The command line args are used mainly when starting an application automatically from another application, or from a shortcut link etc, and I think are the wrong option for this kind of problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Another thing that the tutorial mentioned: Notice that the using directive at the beginning of the file enables you to use the unqualified class names to reference the DLL methods at compile time, as follows:

`MathClass.Add(num1, num2);`

Comment: Do i have to use that line of code to get the output. If yes, where do i place that line of code?

Comment: Where are you trying to "get the output" to exactly?  Because you've actually already stored the output in the `sum` and `subtract` variables you have.  Your program doesn't seem to be getting to that point because you're not passing any command line args, so your `if (args.Length != 2)` means you return before you do any calculating...

Comment: I want to get the output from the console. I want the user to be able to  input integers into the console and the console will display the result using the function from the referenced dll file.

Comment: If that is not possible, i would at least like to hard code the two integers in the program.cs (which is the console application) and when i run the console application, the console would show `1 + 1 = 2` `1 - 1 = 0`

Comment: This is the tutorial that i am referring to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: To achieve what you want, you're going about it in the wrong way.  Ignore the command line args for now, deviate from the tutorial, because your requirement isn't what that tutorial describes.  It's close, but not exact.  If I understand you correctly, you want to have the user type into a console, and then see the result.  That's it.  In that case, just do what I said and ignore the commandline args, and use the Console.ReadLine method.  You've already linked the DLL, that's why you can even use the `MathClass.Add` method at all!

Comment: yes u did understand what i wanted. I will follow what you said. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Please mark as answer id this solved your problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to call run the 'executable' file without the required arguments.

To run an executable file with arguments, you need to do the following.

1) Start the command prompt.

```
(Windows Key + R -> cmd)
```

2) Change current directory to your Console Application projects 'Debug' folder

```
 (Eg., cd C:\YourProjectFolder\bin\debug)
```

3) Enter name of executable with arguments

```
(Eg., C:\YourProjectFolder\bin\debug>YourExecutableName 1 1)
```

Comment: This method works too however when i run the console application, i want the user to be able to input integers right there. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on running from Visual Studio, you need to open your project's properties, click the *Debug* tab and enter your numbers as *Command line arguments*. You will not be able to see the results unless you add a *Console.ReadLine()* at the end of your program. I often do this:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Console.Write("Press <Return>");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If run from inside Visual Studio, if will wait for a Carriage Return, otherwise not.